# Prove, if $\delta>0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\delta<|s|<a}K_n(s)ds=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Prove, if $\delta>0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\delta<|s|<a}K_n(s)ds=0$ if
$$K_n(s)=
\begin{cases}
&n, |s|<1/2n\\
&0, |s|>1/2n
\end{cases}
$$
This shouldn't be too difficult, but I'm struggling somewhat. If I just set up the problem, then we have
$$\int_{-1/2n}^{-\delta}n ds+\int_{\delta}^{1/2n}n ds=1-2n\delta$$
and clearly taking the limit does not give us the desired result. Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Your calculation of the integral is valid only if $\delta <\frac  1 {2n}$. If  $\delta >\frac  1 {2n}$ you will get $0$ instead of $1-2n\delta$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $n >\frac 1 {2\delta}$ then the set $\{s: \delta <|s|<a\}\cap \{s:|s|<\frac 1 {2n}\}$ is the empty set.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you. However, in your comment, you mentioned if $\delta>\frac{1}{2n}$, we get 0. I get your reasoning with the set, but if we just set up the case $\delta>\frac{1}{2n}$ in a similar fashion to the integral in the OP, then we just get $2n\delta-1$. Can't we show that the integral actually goes to zero instead of considering the set?

Comment: You cannot write $\int_{2<x<1} f(x)dx=-\int_1^{2}f(x)dx$.  $\int_{2<x<1} f(x)dx=0$ because you are integrating $f$ over the empty set.  $\int_{2<x<1} f(x)dx$ is not the same as $\int_2^{1}f(x)dx$. @William